# Spring Twitter Integration , Failed to send Status update. Detailed Error: 403:The request is understood, but it has been refused

Tags: spring-integration, spring-social, spring-social-twitter

I am following the Spring Twitter Integration example from Pro Spring Integration book by Mark Lui and Josh Long.

But getting error saying Failed to send Status update.  Detailed Error: 403:The request is understood, but it has been refused.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.twitter.outbound.StatusUpdatingMessageHandler#0]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:84)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:110)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:44)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:157)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:128)
at edureka.TwitterOutbound.main(TwitterOutbound.java:18)

Caused by: org.springframework.integration.twitter.core.TwitterOperationException: Failed to send Status update.  Detailed Error: 403:The request is understood, but it has been refused.  An accompanying error message will explain why.
For more information about this exception please visit the following Twitter website: http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554652/HTTP-Response-Codes-and-Errors
at org.springframework.integration.twitter.core.Twitter4jTemplate.updateStatus(Twitter4jTemplate.java:179)
at org.springframework.integration.twitter.outbound.StatusUpdatingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(StatusUpdatingMessageHandler.java:57)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
... 6 more
```

What could be the problem

Here is my TwitterOutbound.java

```
public class TwitterOutbound {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "/twitter-outbound.xml", TwitterOutbound.class);
    MessageChannel input = context.getBean("twitterOutbound",
            MessageChannel.class);
    Message<String> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(
            "Only can get and send message once "
                    + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()).build();
    input.send(message);
    context.stop();
}
}
```

and twitter-outbound.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:twitter="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/twitter"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/twitter
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/twitter/spring-integration-twitter-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="edureka"/>
<context:property-placeholder location="/twitter.properties"/>
<int:channel id="twitterOutbound"/> 

<twitter:outbound-channel-adapter twitter-template="twitterTemplate"
channel="twitterOutbound"/>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

`403` means your credentials are incorrect.

You need to verify your OAuth `consumerKey`, `consumerSecret`, `accessToken` and `accessTokenSecret` are correctly configured.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I disagree; `What could be the problem` was the question and I answered that; but I've added some clarification.

Comment: I agree that you did answer that question, but was that really all what the OP wanted to know? I bet he needed more. Your edit does give a little more sauce, so let's see what the OP will say about it.